# JAVA, ANDROID: setImageResource(int) not displaying image

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, drawable

I have a code, that should display each item in **bank** a different image, and if it cant find one: display a default one.
I have got everything to work, except the problem is that it does not display the drawables. How can i fix it?

My code:

```
  public class BankViewFragment extends OSRSFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "BankViewFragment";

    private static Account account;
    private ListView lv;
    Handler handler;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ItemList;

    public static BankViewFragment newInstance(final Account account) {
        BankViewFragment fragment = new BankViewFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bank_view, null);
        ItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        new GetItems().execute();
        lv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        return view;
    }

    public static int getResId(String resourceName, Class<?> c) {
        try {
            Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(resourceName);
            return idField.getInt(idField);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No resource ID found for: "
                    + resourceName + " / " + c, e);
        }
    }

    private class GetItems extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("minescape", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String nikas = sharedpreferences.getString("bankname",  "null");
            String url = "https://api.minesca.pe/game/classic/stats?username=" + nikas;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "NIKAS: " + nikas);
            Log.e(TAG, "ACCOUNT: " + account);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONObject items = jsonObj.getJSONObject("bank");
                    Iterator keys = items.keys();
                    while(keys.hasNext()) {
                        String dynamicKey = (String)keys.next();
                        JSONObject line = items.getJSONObject(dynamicKey);
                        String item = line.getString("item");
                        //Integer image = getResId(item, Drawable.class);
                        final Integer image = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
                        String amount = line.getString("amount");
                        Log.e(TAG, "DAIKTAS: " + item);
                        Log.e(TAG, "KIEKIS: " + amount);
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                        String itembank = item.replaceAll("i_", "");
                        String itembanks = itembank.replaceAll("_", " ");
                        contact.put("name", itembanks);
                        contact.put("email", amount);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                      //  lv = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
                       // iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                        final ImageView ims = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logo);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if(image != null) {
                                    if(image == 0) {
                                        ims.setImageResource(R.drawable.i_noted);
                                        Log.e(TAG, "rokas?: " + image);
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "drawable ID ID: " + image);
                                        ims.setImageResource(image);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "null?: " + image);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        ItemList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    };

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                };
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), ItemList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "email","name"},
                    new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.name});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    }
```

Logcat keeps messaging me this:
`02-08 14:11:12.331 17584-17584/com.infonuascape.osrshelper W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x601 a=1 r=0x10500d7}`

Comment: You're setting that image resource on an `ImageView` in a `View` that you inflate, but never add to the on-screen hierarchy. Basically, it's just discarded after each time through the loop.

Comment: Your updating UI in background thread ...

Comment: Could you guys show me an example of what i do wrong? Im kinda new to JAVA, and i need to finish it today. Thanks for the help! <3

Comment: OSRSFragment,  what is that class?  Anyway Its not the proper way to update or set values in doInBackground. Make sure that setting values willl be in onPostexcecute. And i've doubt about  postdelayed inside async task.

Comment: Thanks, how can i transfer the setting code to onPostexcecute?

Comment: Easiest solution: add a third entry to the `contact` `Map` for the image and the resource ID; e.g., `contact.put("image", String.valueOf(image));`. Then modify the arrays in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor call accordingly - `new String[]{ "email","name", "image"}` and `new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.name, R.id.logo}`.

Comment: just transfer handler.post contents to onPostexcute. And always try to declare and objects globally and define it in onCreate. I dnt know that will help you to resolve issue , but try it

Comment: Forgot to mention, get rid of the `View` inflation and `setImageResource()` stuff you have in the loop.

Comment: @MikeM. I LOVE YOU! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I also forgot to mention that you still want to do your `if(image == 0)` check, and do `contact.put("image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.i_noted));` for the default case. Don't need the `handler.post()`, though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should choose right setter:

- **`imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)`** - to set drawable which you can get from 
  resources using `getResource().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_id)`.
- **`imageView.setImageResource(id)`** - to set image using resources id.
- **`imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`** - to set bitmap which you can create from drawable using:`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.drawable_id)`.

And if you are using `getResources().getIdentifier(...);` I offer you to use:

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(item, "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
imageview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable );
```

Something like this...